A generalisation of $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e-(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}} }{x}$.
I saw this problem:-

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e-(x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}} }{x}.$$

Which can be easily done with l'hopital's rule. Here I wonder what happen if I did the following:  Let $f_0(x):= (x+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}, \ l_0 =e$, $f_{n+1}(x) = \frac{l_n - f_n(x)}{x}$ and $l_{n+1} =\lim\limits_{x \to 0}  f_{n+1}(x)$.
The first values
$$l_0 =e$$
$$l_1= \frac{e}{2}$$
$$l_2= \frac{11e}{24}$$
$$l_3= \frac{7e}{16}$$
$$l_4= \frac{2447e}{5760}$$
$$l_5= \frac{959e}{2304}$$
$$l_6= \frac{238043e}{580608}$$
Graphing the first $6$ functions seem to tell this sequence converge (aside from the obvious error in graphing that the calculator made)

It seems that the limit is $0.4 e$ or at least greater than that.  I was not able to find a limit. I tried to prove the existence of the limit but failed to do that too.
I want to ask what is the limit of this sequence ? Is there a way to determine the $n-$th term ($l_n$)?

$(x + 1)^{\frac{1}{x}}  = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n l_n x^n }$ as $x\to 0^+$, and see http://vadim.sdsu.edu/asymptotic-revisited.pdf and http://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.03794.pdf

@Gary. I did not find the limit. Any idea ? Thanks

@ClaudeLeibovici It is in the second paper: $l_n \to 1$. It seems you computed $l_n/\mathrm{e}$ and not $l_n$ in your table.

@Gary. My mistake. Thanks again. I have to change my screen teller.

@Gary How did you find these? Is there a way to effectively search for mathematical paper like these ?

@pie I remembered them.

Ommiting the $e$, numerators and denominators form respectively sequences $A055505$ and $A055535$ in $OEIS$.
If you look at the Mathematica section, you will find the formula. It write
$$\frac{l_n} e=\frac {(-1)^n}{(2n)! }\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2 n}{k+n}\,\, S_{k+n}^{(k)}\,\ \Gamma (n-k+1,-1)$$
Computing them and converting to decimals, the convergence is very slow
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & \frac{l_n} e\\
 1000 & 0.36824459 \\
 2000 & 0.36806263 \\
 3000 & 0.36800172 \\
 4000 & 0.36797121 \\
 5000 & 0.36795288 \\
 6000 & 0.36794066 \\
 7000 & 0.36793192 \\
 8000 & 0.36792537 \\
 9000 & 0.36792027 \\
 10000 & 0.36791619 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
which is $\frac 1 e$ then $1$ for the limit.

Is $I_n$ the OP's $l_n$?

@Gary : yes, it is. I shall fix it. Thanks
